# Why does std::get only have two function overloads for ranges::subrange?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

There are four pair-like types in the standard, namely `std::array`, `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, and [`ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange), where the overload of `std::get` for `ranges::subrange` is defined in [[range.subrange#access-10]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.subrange#access-10):

> ```
> template<size_t N, class I, class S, subrange_kind K>
>   requires (N < 2)
>   constexpr auto get(const subrange<I, S, K>& r);
> template<size_t N, class I, class S, subrange_kind K>
>   requires (N < 2)
>   constexpr auto get(subrange<I, S, K>&& r);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if constexpr (N == 0)
>   return r.begin(); 
> else
>   return r.end();
> ```

And `ranges::subrange::begin()` has two overloads:

```
constexpr I begin() const requires copyable<I>;
[[nodiscard]] constexpr I begin() requires (!copyable<I>);
```

I noticed that this `std::get` only has **two** overloads, and there is no corresponding overload for non-const lvalue reference, which makes it impossible for us to apply `std::get` to lvalue `input_range` with non-`copyable` iterator [(godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/Mvd69feqx):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  auto ints = std::istringstream{"42"};
  auto is = std::ranges::istream_view<int>(ints);
  std::ranges::input_range auto r = std::ranges::subrange(is);
  auto b  = r.begin();      // OK
  auto b2 = std::get<0>(r); // Error, passing 'const subrange' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers
}
```

So why does `std::get` only have two function overloads for `ranges::subrange`? Does it miss the overloads for `ranges::subrange&` and `const ranges::subrange&&`? Is this a standard defect or is it intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, a fully-formed `subrange` in well-defined code represents a valid range, and if it stores a size, then the size is equal to the size of the range. This is reflected in the precondition of every non-default constructor (the default constructed state can still be partially-formed). This got slightly muddled by the introduction of move-only iterators (since the non-const `begin` needs to move the iterator out) but remains the design intent.

In other words, `subrange` is quite unlike `pair`, `tuple`, or `array`. Those three are aggregates of values with no semantics, and their `get` overloads reflect that by transparently propagating cv-qualification and value category. `subrange`, on the other hand, does have semantics - it's not merely a pair of iterator and sentinel. Its `get` is only for reading, never for writing. That's why `get` on a `subrange` returns by value.

It doesn't make much sense to provide a non-const lvalue `get` overload; returning by mutable reference is out of the question; returning by reference to const is unlike everything else (and also surprising). Returning by value means that in the only case it makes a difference, `get` on an lvalue `subrange` is a destructive operation, which would be quite unexpected.

Comment: Another question is, should we make additional constraints for the first overload to eliminate the "discarded const qualifier" error that occurs inside the function body? I plan to submit an LWG for it, but I don't know if it is worth it.

Comment: I see no reason to ban `get<1>` any more than `.end()`. It's entirely harmless and could be useful. I can see some value in checking that `begin` can be called in the constraint  though.